# OpenAPI Maven Generator generates inexistent '@OptionsMapping' annotation for Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, springfox, openapi-generator

When using 'openapi-generator-maven-plugin' to generate a client based on a jar.

Here is my important pom.xml parts:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-engine-rest-openapi</artifactId>
            <version>${camunda.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>camunda-bpm-nexus</id>
            <name>camunda-bpm-nexus</name>
            <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>camunda-engine-rest-openapi</artifactId>
                                    <version>${camunda.version}</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/openapi</outputDirectory>
                                    <includes>openapi.json</includes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/target/openapi/openapi.json</inputSpec>
                            <skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>true</skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <library>spring-boot</library>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            </configOptions>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/camunda-openapi-client</output>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

For some reason the generator creates a "@OptionsMapping" annotation that does not exist anywhere. Eg.:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Tenant Resource Options", nickname = "availableTenantResourceOperations", notes = "The `/tenant` resource supports two custom OPTIONS requests, this one for the resource as such and one for individual tenant instances. The OPTIONS request allows checking for the set of available operations that the currently authenticated user can perform on the `/tenant` resource. If the user can perform an operation or not may depend on various things, including the users authorizations to interact with this resource and the internal configuration of the process engine.", response = ResourceOptionsDto.class, tags={ "Tenant", })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Request successful.", response = ResourceOptionsDto.class) })
@OptionsMapping(
    value = "/tenant",
    produces = { "application/json" }
)
default ResponseEntity<ResourceOptionsDto> availableTenantResourceOperations() {
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in newer versions of the library.

Please upgrade or follow the Github issues of the library about this.